# How to get a shape/picture coordinates in pixels in an excel file (xlsx) using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

Has anyone succeeded in obtaining the x and y coordinate in pixels of a shape or a picture in a sheet in an excel 2010 file using epplus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution using internal xml data, it seems that excel is using a unit for measure called `EMU` which is `equal to 1/9525 pixel`. the solution is below

```
public static Rectangle GetDimensions(string shapeName, ExcelWorksheet sheet)
{
  const int EMU = 9525;
  var shapeBaseNodexPath = string.Format("//*[@name='{0}']", shapeName);

  //get node that contains name of the shape
  var shapeNameNode = sheet.Drawings.DrawingXml.SelectSingleNode(shapeBaseNode);

  if (shapeNameNode == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid shape name");
  //go 2 levels up and select shape properties node <a:xfrm> node
  var propertiesNode = shapeNameNode
    .SelectSingleNode("../../*[local-name() = 'spPr']/*[local-name() = 'xfrm']");
  if (propertiesNode == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not parse Excel file xml data");

  //get coodinates and size nodes
  var locationNode = propertiesNode.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name() = 'off']");
  var sizeNode = propertiesNode.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name() = 'ext']");

  //create Rectangle
  int x, y, w, h = 0;
  x = int.Parse(locationNode.Attributes["x"].Value) / EMU;
  y = int.Parse(locationNode.Attributes["y"].Value) / EMU;
  w = int.Parse(sizeNode.Attributes["cx"].Value) / EMU;
  h = int.Parse(sizeNode.Attributes["cy"].Value) / EMU;

  return new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Comment: Where did you get that actual number (1045,451) from?  When I run your function against the excel file I created with a single pic yours actually comes up a little short.  In my test my func gives a width of 140 while yours gives 131.  I put the picture just inisde Col C and if I count the widths of Cols A and B in Excel itself I get 137.  The 3 pixel difference looks about right for the gap between the start of Col C and the image.  I updated my post to show what I mean.  Note that if I set the two column widths the same (say 65 px) then I get 131 for BOTH funcs.

Comment: I used two methods, the 1st is using an on screen coordinate tool 2nd by checking the drawings xml file inside xlsx file which my method is based on both methods gave me the same result. according to this source http://officeopenxml.com/drwSp-size.php the values in `xfrm` tag designate the coordinates and size of a shape in EMU.

Answer (score 1):

Its not pretty unfortunately.  The functions you really need are `GetPixelTop` and `GetPixelLeft` in the file `ExcelDrawingBase.cs` but they are marked as `internal`:  http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/Drawing/ExcelDrawingBase.cs.  So you cannot really call them without modification to the source code.

The simplest would simply be to recreate your own version.  Here is a quick cut/paste (make sure you QA well before going to production):

```
public int DrawingPixelX(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, ExcelDrawing drawing)
{
    const int emuPerPixel = ExcelDrawing.EMU_PER_PIXEL;
    decimal mdw = worksheet.Workbook.MaxFontWidth;

    var pix = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= drawing.From.Column; i++)
        pix += (int)decimal.Truncate(((256 * (decimal)worksheet.Column(i).Width + decimal.Truncate(128 / mdw)) / 256) * mdw);

    pix += drawing.From.ColumnOff / emuPerPixel;
    return pix;
}

public int DrawingPixelY(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, ExcelDrawing drawing)
{
    const int emuPerPixel = ExcelDrawing.EMU_PER_PIXEL;

    var piy = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= drawing.From.Row; i++)
        piy += (int)(worksheet.Row(i).Height / 0.75);

    piy += drawing.From.RowOff / emuPerPixel;
    return piy;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var workbook = package.Workbook;
var ws = workbook.Worksheets.First();
var pic = ws.Drawings.First();

Console.WriteLine(DrawingPixelX(ws, pic));
Console.WriteLine(DrawingPixelY(ws, pic));
```

I get a Left and Top of 141 and 43 for the attached image.

[image]

Comment: TY for help, I already tried this approach but unfortunately does not give accurate coordinates for 'X', I have a shape that is located in (1045,451)pixel with the above I get different value x=1067.

Comment: The gap becomes more clear when x > 1000, I made another test which resulted in 1895 vs real 1853.

Comment: How did you get "real"?  I tried the same with different column widths totaling over 1200 and both functions return the same (correct numbers) based on counting column widths in the GUI.

Comment: Please check my comment below. The subject is getting hot, I wonder who is correct, you, or me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can read it from internal `ExcelDrawing` internal fields `_widht` and `_height`. Thanks to @Ernie for pointing to the `ExcelDrawingBase.cs`.

```
shape = (ExcelShape) xls.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Drawings["MyShape"];
var width = (int) shape.GetType()
        .GetProperty("_width", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(shape);
var height = (int) shape.GetType()
        .GetProperty("_height", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(shape);
```

*Edit:* This method is tested only on EPP 4, the current version EPP 5 internal implementation might have changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this example. I tried this but I get Null value returned at the GetProperty("_width") step and then  the GetValue(shape) fails. Has anyone succeeded in this right?

Comment: @DK2014 If `_width` and `_height` are fields and not properties then you probably just need to use `.GetField()` instead of `.GetProperty`.