# EPPlus: How to get the absolute Position of a ExcelDrawing

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Im currently working on a shared interface for the Excel.Interop and EPPlus libraries. Now im trying to get the coordinates for a shape (ExcelDrawing). In Excel.Interop i can use Left/Top/Width/Height etc. but with EPPlus i could not receive the same values as with the Interop Library. 
ExcelDrawing.From.ColumnOff gives me the offset from the left edge of the Picture to the column where it is anchored to. So now i just tried to sum up all the column widths until i reach the anchor-column and add the offset to it. But still, i get completely different values.
Here is my Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //EPPlus test
        var fileName = @"C:\Users\dse31131\Desktop\bla.xlsx";
        var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
        var exp = new ExcelPackage(fi, false);
        var sheet = exp.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        var graphic = sheet.Drawings.FirstOrDefault();

        var startColumn = graphic.From.Column;
        var startColumnPx = sheet.Column(startColumn).Width;

        var absColumnPx = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= startColumn; i++)
            absColumnPx += sheet.Column(i).Width;

        //This is returning 24.28125
        var absGraphicLeft = (absColumnPx + (graphic.From.ColumnOff / 9525.0));

        exp.Dispose();

        ////ExcelInterop test
        var application = new Application();
        var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

        var colWidth = worksheet.Columns[1].ColumnWidth;
        var shapes = worksheet.Shapes;
        var shape = (from Shape x in shapes select x).FirstOrDefault();
        //This is returning 100.5 (i am not sure which unit this should be..)
        var interopabsGraphicLeft = shape.Left;

        workbook.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This post might helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463291/how-to-get-a-shape-picture-coordinates-in-pixels-in-an-excel-file-xlsx-using-e/36481837  The OP tried one way via xml, I try another way based on the the EPPlus source code.  He seems to thing his way works while mine does not.  I find the opposite.  So try both and see which works for you.

Comment: Thank you Ernie, i will try your solution!